# Webpack выдает ошибку при инициализации переменной Static

Tags: javascript, webpack, static, babel

Совсем недавно в этой сфере, поэтому задавать вопросы буду как умею :)

**Использую переменную static в коде.**

```
import {ExelComponent} from "@core/ExelComponent";

export class Formula extends ExelComponent {
    // статическая - доступ без инстанса класса
    static className = 'exel__fomula'

    toHTML() {
        return '<h1> Formula </h1>'
    }
}
```

**Далее установил плагин для babel @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
и добавил его в конфиг**

```
const loaders = [
    {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
        }
    }
]
```

**При запуске появляется ошибка.**

> ERROR in ./src/components/formula/Formula.js 5:21
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:21)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> | export class Formula extends ExelComponent {
> |     // статическая - доступ без инстанса класса
> static className = 'exel__fomula'
> |
> |     toHTML() {

**Понимаю, что нужно что-то установить, но не понимаю как и что искать.
Буду благодарен за помощь.
Спасибо!**

Comment: А ExelComponent  это что?

Comment: Это просто класс, от которого наследуется Formula.  ExelComponent пустой.

Comment: Я знаю что такое extends)). Вопрос где вы его импортируете

Comment: Отредактировал код в этом вопросе, импорт был выше класса formula в коде.

Comment: Вместо обычной переменной я создал static функцию, которая возвращает строчку. Ошибка пропала. Если использовать эту функцию в дальнейшем, теоретически, могу ли я наткнуться на какие то ошибки/баги?